# Connecting to my Hyper V server from Windows 8 Laptop

Tags: windows-8, hyper-v

I have my Windows Server 2012 Hyper-V server running on a HP DL Server. I am connected to my local wireless network so my laptop has an ip address of 10.0.0.20 say. I installed Hyperv Server with a Static IP Address of 10.0.0.50 with the same subnet mask of 255.255.255.0 and gateway for HyperV server as 10.0.0.40.

I am trying to use hyperV manager to connect to my server. I am not able to connect. I get an error message when I connect to 10.0.0.50 as follows:

An error occurred while attempting to connect to server 10.0.0.50, check that the virtual machine management service is running and that you are authorized to connect to the server.

Appreciate your help

Comment: Is the firewall on the server open?